# Facebook Graph API not getting all events, even if 'hosted by'

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the FB Graph API and not getting all the events.  I know through searching this forum that only events that are 'hosted by' the group come through but I am not event getting all the events 'hosted by' the groups.

For example, I am trying to get the events from https://www.facebook.com/pg/goldenlionbristol/events/.  The event on 1st Nov 2017, https://www.facebook.com/events/315066482344970/ is hosted by The Golden Lion but is not coming through.  Nether is the one on 2nd November 2017, https://www.facebook.com/events/153007618626727/, which is also hosted by The Golden Lion.

The code (ruby) I am using

```
Koala.config.api_version = 'v2.10'
oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new app_id, app_secret
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new oauth.get_app_access_token
fb_events = graph.get_object( fb_venue["url_listings"] )
```

For the example above fb_venue["url_listings"] = 'goldenlionbristol/events'.  This is working fine for other groups (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/pg/MrWolfs/events/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are not returned in order of which is closest to the current date (which a simple look at the result should have made obvious), and with the default limit of 25, the first event currently simply is on the second [*page*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging) of results.

The second event is actually a repeating event. Just [look at the return for that one individually by id](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=153007618626727&version=v2.10):

```
  "start_time": "2017-10-05T21:00:00+0100",
  "event_times": [
    {
      "id": "153007635293392",
      "start_time": "2017-11-02T21:00:00+0000",
      "end_time": "2017-11-02T23:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "153007631960059",
      "start_time": "2017-10-05T21:00:00+0100",
      "end_time": "2017-10-05T23:00:00+0100"
    },
    {
      "id": "153007628626726",
      "start_time": "2017-12-07T21:00:00+0000",
      "end_time": "2017-12-07T23:00:00+0000"
    }
  ],
```

So that has two upcoming "occurrences" on Nov 2nd and Dec 7th. Oh, and it already had one on Oct 5th ... and *that* one shows up [on the second page of results](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=114246605339243%2Fevents%3Fpretty%3D0%26fields%3Dname%252Cstart_time%26limit%3D25%26after%3DQVFIUnRWcWV3c3pPRFk1ZA2FfOTZALQW05WTJ5Mi1rWmJSei1wS2tWWjdneTgxSy1DVFpTSnFHbFdVVTB3RVNFQUxHYkRuOEo1RzJwanppLWZAVU0pRelFZALTZAB&version=v2.10) as well.

You will have to get to the repeated occurrences via the "original" event, and have to go back in events until you catch it. In the API reference for the event object there's no mention of repeating events, so it looks like it has not kept up with the evolution of UI features in that regard.

Comment: Thanks, I realized the events are not returned in a particulate order but did not realize the default limit was 25, I am now getting the results in 'pages'. using 'fb_events = fb_events.next_page'.